# GAE - wordpress as a module inside a Python app

Tags: php, python, wordpress, google-app-engine, module

Google App Engine recently added support for modules. And I'm almost certain I remember someone saying you can have modules with different runtimes. Your default app can be Python and a module could be in Java or PHP for example. And the module configuration file does make you specify the runtime for that module.

So why then can I not figure out how to run a PHP module inside a Python app?

I have a `dispatch.yaml` that contains:

```
dispatch:
- url: "*/blog*"
  module: blog
```

And a `blog.yaml` for the module which contains:

```
module: blog
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1
```

and a bunch of handlers for Wordpress.

Has anyone else been able to do this successfully?

In this case I want to run a wordpress blog under `http:/www.domain.com/blog` instead of under a sub-domain for SEO reasons.

It seems the appengine SDK is not using the module because if I try to go to `/blog` it just gives me a 404 error.

I'll continue to play with this and post an update if I find a solution.

Comment: If you find a solution feel free to post that as an *answer* below.

Comment: Looks about right.  Are you sure your wordpress site isn't returning a 404?

Comment: Using PHP with modules is not quite supported yet - there are a couple of bugs, one of them causes a 404. We're working on it.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, do I have to wait for an SDK update or is there a bug I can follow?

Comment: I've submitted this as an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9862 as I was not able to find anything existing on this topic.

I guess the reason for this is that the PHP runtime does not yet support being a module.

Comment: I have this working now using GAE 1.8.5. Once I have it deployed will post the entire configuration I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have everything working now. Google fixed some issues in version 1.8.5 making this possible. It's actually not that hard, you just have to remember to run appcfg.py update_dispatch in order to make the dispatch routing live. And also when deploying do appcfg.py update app.yaml wordpress.yaml
That way both configurations are uploaded and deployed.

Currently git push to deploy is still broken and in order to upload images wordpress wp-admin has to be running on the appspot.com domain which is not too big of a deal.

I wrote a blog post describing everything that I did to make it work:
http://blog.artooro.com/2013/10/09/run-wordpress-as-a-module-on-google-app-engine/